# The Like Link don't work correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a quick question, maybe someone can help me.

I have some items that will each receive a like-link, that works quite well, only when transferred to FB the link is "cut".

Instead, of www.domain.de/news/name-der-news/&pos=1 he gives only 
www.domain.de/news/name-der-news/

Have you any idea how I can fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to url encode it, so that special characters will be encoded, such as '?', '=', etc...

With your example, the encoded url is:
`www.domain.de%2Fnews%2Fname-der-news%2F%26pos%3D1`

Here's an online url encoder/decoder: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: Hi Thanks...

But it won't work... :(
I tryed it... in the link it is korrekt, but if i click on the link in fb it's missing the &pos=1 ...

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sure... 
The link is e.g. http://www.hagelshop-lounge.de/news/13/21/Rock-your-style/&pos=1
and the code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={$cgsimple->self_url()|replace:":":"%3A"|replace:"/":"%2F"|replace:"&":"%26"|replace:"=":"%3D"}&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Written like that the the link will look like this:

http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hagelshop-lounge.de%2Fnews%2F13%2F21%2FRock-your-style%2F%26pos%3D1

but still the **&pos=1** will be missing...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Does Facebook strip the URL down to the path only (removing query) for like purposes? This would be bad for many apps. I suppose you could resort to tinyurl to get around this.